# exist some method for handle the click on predefined location button in google maps Api 2?

Tags: android, google-maps, click

http://www.flickr.com/photos/95897065@N03/8758730915/

exist some method for handle clicks in this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as of rev.7 of API v2. Hopefully it will be added in the near future. Feature request for this exists on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

**Edit:**

This is now available via

```
map.setOnMyLocationClickListener(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that button to be shown by doing something like this:

```
private GoogleMap map;
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);   // !!! important part
```